# How to add Map values to List in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am confusing some Map to List conversion in dart.
For example;

```
Map<String ,dynamic> datas=  "RJGas": {
        "unit_deatils": {
            "total_obs": 3,
            "previous_obs": 3,
            "difference": 0,
            "indicator": "green",
            "critical_period": [
                "17:00",
                "17:59"
            ],
            "critical_obs": "HK"
        },
        "zone_deatils": {
            "RGT Well Pads 04": {
                "total_obs": 0,
                "previous_obs": 2,
                "difference": -2,
                "indicator": "green",
                "critical_period": [],
                "critical_obs": ""
            },
            "RGT Well pads 01": {
                "total_obs": 2,
                "previous_obs": 0,
                "difference": 2,
                "indicator": "red",
                "critical_period": [
                    "17:00",
                    "17:59"
                ],
                "critical_obs": "HK"
            },
            "RGT Well": {
                "total_obs": 1,
                "previous_obs": 1,
                "difference": 0,
                "indicator": "green",
                "critical_period": [],
                "critical_obs": ""
            },
            "RGT Well 01": {
                "total_obs": 0,
                "previous_obs": 0,
                "difference": 0,
                "indicator": "green",
                "critical_period": [],
                "critical_obs": ""
            }
        }
    },
```

I want to get a list include only zone details data, how to get all zone details in to a List,
I want to the output be like,

```
 List zoneDatas = [
     "RGT Well Pads 04": {
                        "total_obs": 0,
                        "previous_obs": 2,
                        "difference": -2,
                        "indicator": "green",
                        "critical_period": [],
                        "critical_obs": ""
                    },
                    "RGT Well pads 01": {
                        "total_obs": 2,
                        "previous_obs": 0,
                        "difference": 2,
                        "indicator": "red",
                        "critical_period": [
                            "17:00",
                            "17:59"
                        ],
                        "critical_obs": "HK"
                    },
                    "RGT Well": {
                        "total_obs": 1,
                        "previous_obs": 1,
                        "difference": 0,
                        "indicator": "green",
                        "critical_period": [],
                        "critical_obs": ""
                    },
                    "RGT Well 01": {
                        "total_obs": 0,
                        "previous_obs": 0,
                        "difference": 0,
                        "indicator": "green",
                        "critical_period": [],
                        "critical_obs": ""
                    }
    ]
```

I am stucking this map to List conversion, Please add your valuable replays,hopefully

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
List zoneDatas = [];

datas["RJGas"]["zone_deatils"].forEach((key, value) {
  zoneDatas.add({key: value});
});

print(zoneDatas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `datas` declaration is not correct, I think you should add some `{` like this:

```dart
Map<String ,dynamic> datas=  {"RJGas": {
        "unit_deatils": {
            "total_obs": 3,
            "previous_obs": 3,
            "difference": 0,
            "indicator": "green",
            "critical_period": [
                "17:00",
                "17:59"
            ],
            "critical_obs": "HK"
        },
        "zone_deatils": {
            "RGT Well Pads 04": {
                "total_obs": 0,
                "previous_obs": 2,
                "difference": -2,
                "indicator": "green",
                "critical_period": [],
                "critical_obs": ""
            },
            "RGT Well pads 01": {
                "total_obs": 2,
                "previous_obs": 0,
                "difference": 2,
                "indicator": "red",
                "critical_period": [
                    "17:00",
                    "17:59"
                ],
                "critical_obs": "HK"
            },
            "RGT Well": {
                "total_obs": 1,
                "previous_obs": 1,
                "difference": 0,
                "indicator": "green",
                "critical_period": [],
                "critical_obs": ""
            },
            "RGT Well 01": {
                "total_obs": 0,
                "previous_obs": 0,
                "difference": 0,
                "indicator": "green",
                "critical_period": [],
                "critical_obs": ""
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can access `zone_deatils` like this:

```dart
Map zone_details = datas["RJGas"]["zone_deatils"];
```

The output format that you provided is not correct, since it is a map. If you still want a list, then you can try this:

```dart
List zone_details_as_list = datas["RJGas"]["zone_deatils"].values;
```